# Batch Script to Update text in the properties file

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a question regarding the batch.

I have a properties file in Directory. Which has a text "BuildNumber=0". I want to replace this "BuildNumber=0" with "BuildNumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%". I am using the following script to achieve this

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions


ATTRIB -r -s C:\bldarea\myfile\..\..\jenkinstest\abc.properties

CD C:\bldarea\myfile\file\Main_Releases\jenkinstest\
call :FindReplace "Buildnumber=0" "Buildnumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%" abc.properties
exit /b 

:FindReplace <Buildnumber=0> <Buildnumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%> <abc.properties>
set tmp="%temp%\tmp.txt"
If not exist %temp%\_.vbs call :MakeReplace
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "%3" /s /b /a-d /on') do (
for /f "usebackq" %%b in (`Findstr /mic:"%~1" "%%a"`) do (
echo(&Echo Replacing "%~1" with "%~2" in file %%~nxa
<%%a cscript //nologo %temp%\_.vbs "%~1" "%~2">%tmp%
if exist %tmp% move /Y %tmp% "%%~dpnxa">nul
)
)
del %temp%\_.vbs
exit /b

:MakeReplace
>%temp%\_.vbs echo with Wscript
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo set args=.arguments
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo .StdOut.Write _
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo Replace(.StdIn.ReadAll,args(0),args(1),1,-1,1)
>>%temp%\_.vbs echo end with
```

The problem with this script is , It is  not converting BuildNumber=0 to current Build Number.

From the line in code:

```
:FindReplace <Buildnumber=0> <Buildnumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%> <abc.properties>
```

if I remove % symbol then it is printing the "BuildNumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%" but the "BuildNumber=0" is still present in the doc. Can someone please help me out to replace the text correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Is %BUILD_NUMBER% a global environment variable? IF not, where is it coming from? You don't need to alter the routine, just the call to it.

Comment: I am firing a build through jenkins There only I defined %BUILD_NUMBER% as global variable. It changes with every BuildNumber.

Comment: How does Jenkins pass that variable into the batch file?

Comment: I have given the productname_${BUILD_NUMBER} in Jenkins a global environment variable, from which the product get its build number. In jenkins there is an option to Execute Windows Batch. I just put the script over there.

Comment: One more thing jenkins download all its file to a workspace. When all files are downloaded there this script executes. After that the ant runs which creates a zip file of the product

Comment: Hi Matt Is there any other way in bat script from which the same can be achieve the file here shows as  '#Fri Nov 22 18:48:45 IST 2013 BuildType=dev FrameworkBuild=244 BuildNumber=0 ProductVersion=5.00.00 SoftwareFeatureID=99990101 SequenceNumber=20131122 Buildnumber=82 FrameworkVersion=2.50.00'

Comment: Hi Matt the script runs fine I figure out the issue the Ant which runs after the Batch Script is injecting the value in it with the same value. So I think I need to change the script. I just need to ask one more thing. Can you please explain this code to me since i tried to google many term but some of the term are really out of my league. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert double percents in this line:

```
call :FindReplace "Buildnumber=0" "Buildnumber=%BUILD_NUMBER%" abc.properties
```

this way:

```
call :FindReplace "Buildnumber=0" "Buildnumber=%%BUILD_NUMBER%%" abc.properties
```

Comment: Hi Aacini I am still getting the same output in the file. '#Fri Nov 22 18:48:45 IST 2013
BuildType=dev
FrameworkBuild=244
BuildNumber=0
ProductVersion=5.00.00
SoftwareFeatureID=99990101
SequenceNumber=20131122
Buildnumber=82
FrameworkVersion=2.50.00' is there a way to remove this extra buildnumber=0 text.

Comment: Test that `FindReplace` is working properly this way: `call :FindReplace "BuildNumber=0" " " abc.properties`. Run it and check the result... It seems that the replace is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi Aacini, the script runs fine I figure out the issue. The xml running  after the batch script is injecting the value BuildNumber=0. So thanks for the help.